# Timestamp being appended to image urls using ? instead of &

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, image-processing, umbraco, imageresizer

For some reason a timestamp parameter keeps getting appended to the image url which breaks the urls in Chrome due to incorrect formatting.

Example:

```
/media/1033/6199593743576161881eb.jpg?width=230&height=120&bgcolor=000000&mode=crop?timestamp=1373905702716
```

In case it's relevant, this is an Umbraco v6 installation. As a result of this background colour and mode are not applied.

Comment: Seems to be all images using the image resizing.net component. The code is in my post, there is nothing I'm doing server side it happens with static urls that have the width query string parameter which I think the component hijacks and rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ImageResizer does not modify URLs, nor is it aware of a 'timestamp' parameter — something else is causing this!

It's apparent that there is either server-side logic/filtering making this occur, or else a javascript component modifying the DOM.

Viewing the HTML source should tell you whether it's an HTML filter or a javascript snippet.

Typically this kind of behavior is added by a 'debug mode' to eliminate browser caching. I'd watch for any debug settings and see if modifying them solves the problem. If so, please report back here as to the culprit.

Comment: Good catch thanks! I had developer tools open in Chrome. Strangely this should be incorrect behaviour (on Chromes part) since if it wants to append to an existing querystring it should do so using & not ?. Thanks for a great tool.

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools doesn't change the URLs for me. What version/OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 / Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m